# YII Trouble using CUploadedFile::getInstance in Multi FIeld

Tags: yii

I need help, i have 50 filefield when i save with  looping filefield at 26 to 50  do not save file , but filefield 1 to 25 save to datbase. In localhost xampp it run correcly but the trouble when i hosting to webserver. anybody knows what the problem ?. this is my code in controller and form

```
//form
<table>
<tr>
<td>
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'mutu1'); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList(
                        'NilaiStandarMutu[mutu1]',$model->mutu1,
                        array(
                            ''=>'Pilihan',
                             'Ada'=>'Ada',
                            'Tidak Ada'=>'Tidak Ada',
                        )
                    );  
                ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'mutu1'); ?>
</td>
<td style="padding-top:18px;padding-left:100px;padding-right:0px">  
        <?php //echo $form->labelEx($model,'file_mutu1'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->fileField($model,'file_mutu1',array('size'=>10)); ?>

        <?php echo $form->error($model,'file_mutu1'); ?>
</td>
<? 
if(!$model->isNewRecord)
{
?>
<td width=10%>
<? if($model->file_mutu1 <> "") { 
                echo CHtml::link('<i class="icon icon-search"></i> View File ',Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/FileUpload/".$model->file_mutu1, array('target'=>'_blank'));
            } else
            {
                echo CHtml::link('<i class="icon icon-remove"></i> Tidak ada File ','#');

            }

            ?>
</td>
<? } ?>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'mutu2'); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList(
                        'NilaiStandarMutu[mutu2]',$model->mutu2,
                        array(
                            ''=>'Pilihan',
                             'Berjalan'=>'Berjalan',
                            'Tidak Berjalan'=>'Tidak Berjalan',
                        )
                    ); 
                ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'mutu2'); ?>
</td>

<td style="padding-top:18px;padding-left:100px">    
        <?php //echo $form->labelEx($model,'file_mutu1'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->fileField($model,'file_mutu2',array('size'=>10)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'file_mutu2'); ?>
</td>
<? 
if(!$model->isNewRecord)
{
?>
<td width=10%>
<? if($model->file_mutu2 <> "") { 
                echo CHtml::link('<i class="icon icon-search"></i> View File ',Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/FileUpload/".$model->file_mutu2, array('target'=>'_blank'));
            } else
            {
                echo CHtml::link('<i class="icon icon-remove"></i> Tidak ada File ','#');

            }

            ?>
</td>
<? } ?>
</tr>
//....... until 50

//controller
    public function actionCreate()
        {
            $level = Yii::app()->user->getState("level");
            $username = Yii::app()->user->name;

            $month = substr(date('Y-m-d'),0,7); 

            $model=new NilaiStandarMutu;

            if(isset($_POST['NilaiStandarMutu']))
            {

                $model->attributes=$_POST['NilaiStandarMutu'];
                $file_standar_mutu->attributes=$_POST['FileStandarMutu']; 
                $i=1;
                $uploadedFile = array();
                $fileName = array();
                for ($i = 1; $i <= 50; $i++) 
                {
                    $rnd = rand(0,9999); 
                    $nama = 'file_mutu' . '' .$i;

                    $uploadedFile[$i]=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,$nama);
                    //var_dump($uploadedFile['$i']);
                    $fileName[$i] = "{$rnd}-{$uploadedFile[$i]}";  // random number + file name
                    if(!empty($uploadedFile[$i]))
                    {

                        $model->$nama  = $fileName[$i];
                    } 
                }
                if($model->save())
                {
                    $arrlength = count($uploadedFile);
                    for($x = 0; $x <= $arrlength; $x++) {
                                if(!empty($uploadedFile[$x]))  // check if uploaded file is set or not
                                    {
                                        $uploadedFile[$x]->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../FileUpload/'.$fileName[$x]);
                                    }
                            }

                    $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id_nilai_sm));

                }
            }


            if(isset($_GET[mode])=="new")
            {           
                if($level == "prodi")
                {
                        $model->CekJadwal();
                        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
                        $criteria->select = 'tgl_input ';
                        $criteria->condition ="username='$username' and left(tgl_input,7)='$month'";
                        $find = NilaiStandarMutu::model()->count($criteria);
                        if($find >= 1)
                        {
                                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error','Tambah gagal !!, Data sudah ada di tahun yang sama !!');
                                $this->redirect(array("admin"));

                        }   

                }
            }

            $this->render('create',array(
                'model'=>$model,
                'file_standar_mutu' => $file_standar_mutu,
            ));

        }
```

Comment: What are the values of `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` on your localhost and the webserver? Is it always exactly the first 25 that succeed regardless of the files you use to test?

Comment: Also, with 50 uploads, you have about a 12% chance of two $fileName values being the same if they have the same file name originally. The effects get worse the more you upload with the same name, because your random number is just between 0 and 9999. This is a result of what is known as the [Birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Approximations). To avoid that issue, use something like `uniqid()` instead. This issue is not likely the cause of your current problem, but is something you'll want to correct anyway.